# How to access variables from one python file to another

Tags: python, scripting

I'm trying to make a habit tracker and run a login or register script separate from the rest of the program. I'm trying to print the name of the user at the top of the window in customtkinter, but i cant seem to access the username variable created in my login script.

#script 1

```py
from subprocess import call

if self.row_count == 1:
    self.login_window.destroy()
    call(['python3', 'HabitTracker.py'])
```

This is the code i use to call the main habit tracker. this code is in my login script.

#script 2

```py
from main import *
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
         self.mylabel = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.main_window, text='Welcome                       {}'.format(login_reg.username), font=('Arial', 40)).pack(pady=5)
```

This is the code i use to try and access the variable. login_reg is the object i created in the first script.

Comment: Generally not best to use `import *`, instead use something more like `import main as mn` and then get variables from that script using `mn.login_eg.username` in your example. But thats just an aside, to your question, what exactly happens when you try this? You haven't shown us how or where `login_reg` is created? It has to be evaluated on the import of `main` to be accessible if it is an object